# Which maven repositories are checked for my dependencies when using gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

I have a gradle project that has two maven repositories configured. One of them is a nexus repository somewhere on the network and requires authentication. The other is a local maven repository that resides within the project directory structure.

The build should first check if the maven user has access to the nexus repository and if not it should check the local repository to see if it can resolve the dependencies from there.

Reading the documentation [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) I ordered my repositories so that the remote nexus is listed first. I think the documentation states that the repositories are checked in order. This would mean that it tries the remote location first and if it finds a match, we're done. If it doesn't find a match, it will move on to the next repository.

Are my expectations correct?

I've configured the repositories as follows:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://nexus/content/groups/restricted_group"
        credentials {
            username user
            password user
        }
    }

    maven {
        url "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested the build with a user that has access and a user that doesn't have access, and both have a successful build, but I'm not sure which artifact is used for the user that has access.